# Algolia react-instantsearch not returning results when running in next.js dev mode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, algolia

I've got a next.js app that is using aloglia via react-instantsearch package. When I run next.js in dev mode I get not results displayed from react-instantsearch. When I do a "next build" which makes the optimized and then a "next start" the search works and displays results. There are no errors in the console so I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting reactStrictMode: false fixed the issue but I have no idea why. Credit to the person who pointed this fix out to me. https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/3629

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to move from `react-instantsearch-dom` to the newer `react-instantsearch-hooks-web` library for new projects using Algolia InstantSearch.

For older projects, pinning to React 17.x or setting `reactStrictMode: false` in `next.js.config` should keep things running until you can migrate to the new library.